# How to en-queue bootstrap 4 to theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap

i tried enqueue the bootstap with functions php

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap4', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

css seems to work but none of the js files are working..not sure what i am doing wrong..

please help thank

Comment: Is your theme using `wp_head()`?

Comment: yes i am using & confirmed that its having that ..problem seems like : wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true ); is not loading ..others are loading in header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use action hook and enqueue script and style to the site.

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap4', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'boot3','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

If you want to add the scripts after jQuery then you can use the jQuery array for dependent and last argument true will include the JS at footer, if you want the js in header, you can remove that.

Comment: hi..still it's not working ..wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true ); this script is not loading for some reasons..others are showing up

Comment: fixed... the the problem was with the $handle ..boot2 , boot2 :)..thanks for helping out

Comment: You may use correct name like 'popper', 'bootstrap' and a 'popper' as dependency for 'bootstrap' script. You don't need to enqueue jQuery slim :)

Comment: And how can I add the css and script including the tags 'origin' and 'integrity' that are required according to bootstrap?

Comment: If you want the library's styles loaded before all other styles, and the theme's styles loaded after all others (with plugin's styles in the middle), you have to use two functions. The first one, with priority "9", will be used to load the library's styles, and the second one, with priority "10", will be used to load the theme's files. Using only one function to load everything, in a theme, results in a situation where the plugin's styles are the first ones to be loaded.

Comment: why in heaven would you go and enqueue a garbage like Slim jQuery when WP delivers jQuery and loading slim just will break everything out there based on Ajax and the likes?!
To Enqueue Bootstrap you need no slim jQuery. It is plain wrong how this is answered here. Here is what you will need https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thus:
```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.12.9',true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'popper' ),'4.0.0',true );
```

Comment: @BedaSchmid The question was about why his scripts aren't loading, and the reason is he was using the same id twice!

Comment: I disagree. The question is and was "How to en-queue bootstrap 4 to theme?" and the answer is wrong. That answer will destroy any and every AJAX done on site. If we answer, we may as well correct the obvious other mistakes in a issue, because people do actually google and find replies not always with your same state of mind. This is also the reasons we need to _explain_ our answers, something else you didn't do. It would be nice to update the answer, with a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function abc_load_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot3','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'abc_load_my_scripts', 999);
```

With the last argument `array('jquery')` you're telling WP to include the script AFTER jQuery. Note that every script must use a different handle (first parameter).

More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

When you check the `<head>`, are you certain the scripts aren't loaded?

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I tried the above the but the java script file are still not loading ..which make the sub menu and responsive menu toggle un responsive ...i am using chrome and there is not console errors.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: fixed... the the problem was with the $handle ..boot2 , boot2 :)..thanks for helping out

Comment: As usual on Stackoverflow the wrong answers get upvoted and chosen as correct and the only right answers do not even get a vote.
You got my vote now, because you used the proper way of enqueueing anything in WP.